# Redirect from servlet not working

Tags: java, redirect, servlets

We try to send a redirect from our Jersey servlet. seeOther() is returning the status 303 and the correct URL but is not redirecting.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Response redirect()throws URISyntaxException {
    final URI url = new URI("http://www.google.de");
    return Response.seeOther(url).build();
}
```

The Servlet response:

> {"statusType":"SEE_OTHER","entity":null,"entityType":null,"metadata":{"Location":["http://www.google.de"]},"status":303}

We tried temporaryRedirect as well with the same result. The only thing that changed is the status which was 307.

Comment: Is the client configured to handle the redirect?  The redirect location and status is executed by the HTTP client.

Comment: Not realy... we're sending a password reset link to a user via mail --> he calls a method from the server (on localhost:8080) with the link and then he should get redirected from the server to our angular application which is running on localhost:3000! Is there a way to do this?